# vtkProp::SafeDownCast() is crashing when trying to convert a vtkactor

Tags: c++, exception, vtk

From the manual I came to understand that vtksafedowncast is a safe operation. But in my application, sometimes it is crashing when i am trying to convert a vtkactor to vtkprop (This is happening very randomly.). I did check for null before passing vtkactor. Is there any exception handling or some other check to make sure the actor is fit for conversion ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic_cast<> to try, but your compiler must support RTTI.

```
class vtkActor:public vtkProp (){}; //their relationship
```

so you can cast a vtkActor pointer back to vtkProp pointer with dynamic_cast<>.

As for the vtkSafeDowncast, try this.

```
vtkActor * foo ;
foo = vtkActor::New() ;
vtkProp * m_prop ;
m_prop = (vtkProp*)(vtkProp::SafeDownCast(foo));
```

Or if using dynamic_cast<>:

```
m_prop = dynamic_cast<vtkProp*>(foo) ;
```

Comment: vtkProp::SafeDownCast(foo) returns a vtkProp* so directly casting it again is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't even need a cast since vtkActor derives from vtkProp. You can just do

```
vtkProp* p = vtkActor::New();
```